# Displaying Data by Getting data in one row based on four columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, union

I am using select query from three tables using join with where condition. Along with that I have used a case expression.

```
select Staff
    , case when Schedule = 1 then course end as period 1
    , case when Schedule = 2 then course end as period 2
    , case when Schedule = 3 then course end as period 3
from table 1
join 
table 2
on condition...
join table 3 
on condition
where so and so....
group by ...
```

| Staff Name | Period 1 | Period 2 | Period 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Harry | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| Harry | NULL | Music | NULL |
| Harry | NULL | Math's | NULL |
| Harry | Science | NULL | NULL |
| Harry | Null | NULL | French |
| Greg | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| Greg | NULL | English | NULL |
| Greg | History | NULL | NULL |
| Greg | Null | NULL | Geography |
| Greg | NULL | Civics | NULL |
| Greg | philosophy | NULL | NULL |

I am trying to remove Null which are in Period 1, period 2, Period 3. I also tried splitting into three select queries with one statement each in every query by union.
I also tried cross join, but it showed 10,000 entries. I want something like this.

| Staff Name | Period 1 | Period 2 | Period 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Harry | Science | Music | French |
| Harry | NULL | Math's | NULL |
| Greg | History | English | Geography |
| Greg | Philosophy | Civics | NULL |

If one period has multiple courses, then it could be repeated with other periods null, otherwise should be in the same row.

Comment: What dictates whether A or B should be in its own row?

Comment: Why does Greg have E twice?

Comment: Or, alternatively, what defines that A is related to C and D, but B is not, for Harry?

Comment: Also, you seem to be saying that the initial data is a result of a query with CASE expressions. Please include the data used by ***that*** query *(the three source tables)*, as it can possibly all be done in one step.

Comment: Hi A, B,C it's just a random data coming. E second time row could be ignored, added by mistake.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to create conditional aggregation query. If you have multiple courses, you probably need to create a row_number() column containing course rank per period and aggregate on that one as well as name. I suggest including another column specifying the order of periods or something that differenciates the different row per name

Comment: Basically, other tables are joined just for where condition, otherwise data is from table itself.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the data used by your "secret" query *(the three source tables)*, as it can possibly all be done in one step.

Comment: As others have suggested, share the query and sample data that gives you the data you show at the start of the question. It's almost certainly easier to do the work there rather than working with the "*pivoted*" results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still haven't actually given the source data, so I'll infer the source data from your question's query...

```
CREATE TABLE source (
  staff      VARCHAR(32),
  schedule   INT,
  course     VARCHAR(32)
)
```

```
INSERT INTO
  source
VALUES
  ('Harry', 0, NULL),
  ('Harry', 2, 'Music'),
  ('Harry', 2, 'Maths'),
  ('Harry', 1, 'Science'),
  ('Harry', 3, 'French'),
  ('Greg', 0, NULL),
  ('Greg', 2, 'English'),
  ('Greg', 1, 'History'),
  ('Greg', 3, 'Geography'),
  ('Greg', 2, 'Civics'),
  ('Greg', 1, 'Philosophy')
```

```
WITH
  ranked AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY staff, schedule
          ORDER BY course
    )
      AS rank
  FROM
    source
)
SELECT
  staff,
  MAX(CASE WHEN schedule = 1 THEN course END)  AS period_1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN schedule = 2 THEN course END)  AS period_2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN schedule = 3 THEN course END)  AS period_3
FROM
  ranked
GROUP BY
  staff,
  rank
ORDER BY
  staff,
  rank
```

| staff | period_1 | period_2 | period_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Greg | History | Civics | Geography |
| Greg | Philosophy | English | *null* |
| Harry | Science | Maths | French |
| Harry | *null* | Music | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-_hKtYH9)

Comment: It almost worked 95% for me, I am still getting some rows where All Periods are Null.

Comment: @dixitgandhi That's a function of the source data, ***which you still haven't shown us***.

Comment: it worked for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: How about if Staff Name also, I have to show it once. Greg or Harry example?

Comment: @dixitgandhi SO isn't suited to conversationa or questions that grow over time. Open a new question and refer to this one if appropriate.